# Unable to show a floating window in Android app during call state changes

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am working on an Android app where I need to show a floating window during call state changes and send events to a React Native app. Without the floating window, the events are sent successfully, but when trying to show the floating window, I encounter the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.arunkavale.test, PID: 19533
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.arunkavale.test.CallReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4905)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleReceiver(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2498)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8893)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.arunkavale.test.CallModule.showFloatingWindow(CallModule.java:51)
    at com.arunkavale.test.CallModule.sendEvent(CallModule.java:40)
    at com.arunkavale.test.CallReceiver.sendEventToReactNative(CallReceiver.java:60)
    at com.arunkavale.test.CallReceiver.onReceive(CallReceiver.java:48)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4896)
```

Here is an AndroidManifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service
            android:name=".CallBackgroundService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"
            tools:targetApi="q" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION"
            android:value="49.0.0" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH"
            android:value="ALWAYS" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS"
            android:value="0" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="com.arunkavale.test" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".CallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is an CallReceiver

```
package com.arunkavale.test;

// CallReceiver.java
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action != null && action.equals(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if (state != null) {
                if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                    // Handle incoming call
                    String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                    if (phoneNumber != null) {
                        sendEventToReactNative(context, "INCOMING_CALL", phoneNumber);
                    }
                } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                    // Handle outgoing call or call in progress
                    String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                    if (phoneNumber != null) {
                        sendEventToReactNative(context, "OUTGOING_CALL", phoneNumber);
                    }
                } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                    // Handle call ended
                    String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                    if (phoneNumber != null) {
                        sendEventToReactNative(context, "CALL_ENDED", phoneNumber);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendEventToReactNative(Context context, String event, String phoneNumber) {
        Log.d("CallReceiver", "sendEvent " + event + ", phoneNumber: " + phoneNumber);

        // Use your custom native module to send events to React Native
        CallModule.sendEvent(event, phoneNumber);

        // Start the background service only if it hasn't been started yet
        if (!isServiceRunning(context, CallBackgroundService.class)) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, CallBackgroundService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }

    private boolean isServiceRunning(Context context, Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is an callModule

```
 package com.arunkavale.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;

public class CallModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    private static ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
    private static View overlayView;

    public CallModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
        reactContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "CallModule";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void makeCall(String phoneNumber) {
        // Implement code to make outgoing calls
    }

    static void sendEvent(String eventName, String phoneNumber) {
        Log.d("CallModule", "sendEvent " + eventName
                + " phoneNumber " + phoneNumber);
        showFloatingWindow(phoneNumber);
        reactContext
                .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                .emit(eventName, phoneNumber);
    }

    static void showFloatingWindow(String phoneNumber) {
        // Get the WindowManager service
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) reactContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        // Inflate the layout for the floating window
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) reactContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        overlayView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.floating_window_layout, null);

        // Add your custom logic to update the content of the floating window
        TextView textView = overlayView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Calling " + phoneNumber);

        // Set window parameters
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        } else {
            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        }

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        // Add the view to the window manager
        windowManager.addView(overlayView, params);
    }
}
```

Here is an callBackgroundService

```
package com.arunkavale.test;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

// CallBackgroundService.java
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class CallBackgroundService extends Service {

    private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
    private CustomPhoneStateListener phoneStateListener;
    private CallReceiver callReceiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Initialize anything needed for the service here

        // Register the broadcast receiver for custom events
        registerReceiver();

        // Start listening for phone state changes
        startListeningForPhoneState();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Start your background logic here
        sendEventToReactNative("BACKGROUND_EVENT", "Event from background service");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Cleanup or release resources if needed

        // Unregister the broadcast receiver and stop listening for phone state changes
        unregisterReceiver();
        stopListeningForPhoneState();
    }

    private void startListeningForPhoneState() {
        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        phoneStateListener = new CustomPhoneStateListener();
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

    private void stopListeningForPhoneState() {
        if (telephonyManager != null && phoneStateListener != null) {
            telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        }
    }

    private void registerReceiver() {
        callReceiver = new CallReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("your-custom-event");
        registerReceiver(callReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    private void unregisterReceiver() {
        if (callReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(callReceiver);
        }
    }

    private void sendEventToReactNative(String event, String data) {
        // Use your custom native module to send events to React Native
        CallModule.sendEvent(event, data);
    }

    // Custom PhoneStateListener to handle call state changes
    private class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phoneNumber) {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    // Handle incoming call
                    sendEventToReactNative("INCOMING_CALL", phoneNumber);
                    break;

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    // Handle outgoing call or call in progress
                    sendEventToReactNative("OUTGOING_CALL", phoneNumber);
                    break;

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    // Handle call ended
                    sendEventToReactNative("CALL_ENDED", phoneNumber);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect the issue is related to the ReactApplicationContext being null during the call state change. How can I ensure a valid ReactApplicationContext when trying to show the floating window?

Additionally, is there a better approach to handle call state changes and show a floating window in an Android app integrated with React Native?

Any help or guidance is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be with the order in which the ReactApplicationContext is assigned and the CallModule is instantiated. The CallModule may not have been properly initialised, resulting in a null ReactApplicationContext when the CallReceiver calls the sendEventToReactNative method.

Ensuring that the CallModule is initialised before usage is one way to address this issue. Before attempting to utilise it, you can make changes to the CallModule class to make sure the ReactApplicationContext is set.

**This is an updated CallModule for you:**

```
package com.arunkavale.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;

public class CallModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    private static ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
    private static View overlayView;

    public CallModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
        reactContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "CallModule";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void makeCall(String phoneNumber) {
        // Implement code to make outgoing calls
    }

    static void initialize(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        reactContext = context;
    }

    static void sendEvent(String eventName, String phoneNumber) {
        Log.d("CallModule", "sendEvent " + eventName + " phoneNumber " + phoneNumber);

        // Ensure that the ReactApplicationContext is not null
        if (reactContext == null) {
            Log.e("CallModule", "ReactApplicationContext is null. CallModule may not have been properly initialized.");
            return;
        }

        showFloatingWindow(phoneNumber);
        reactContext
                .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                .emit(eventName, phoneNumber);
    }

    static void showFloatingWindow(String phoneNumber) {
        // Get the WindowManager service
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) reactContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        // Inflate the layout for the floating window
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) reactContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        overlayView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.floating_window_layout, null);

        // Add your custom logic to update the content of the floating window
        TextView textView = overlayView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Calling " + phoneNumber);

        // Set window parameters
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        } else {
            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        }

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        // Add the view to the window manager
        windowManager.addView(overlayView, params);
    }
}
```

This is the time to dial CallModule.Make sure that your application calls initialize(reactContext) with a valid ReactApplicationContext before making any calls to sendEvent. You may want to accomplish this in an appropriate app entry point or in the onCreate method of your main application class.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Other initialization code
    CallModule.initialize(new ReactApplicationContext(this));
}
```